# Multiple Files and Namespaces Scope

Tags: php, file, namespaces, scope, global

I'm pretty new to namespaces (and yes, I've read the PHP documentation namespaces section). I'm wondering what the scope of namespaces is with regard to multiple files. Is a namespace valid beyond one file when I include or require that file in a file that has global code? And furthermore, how does that affect the global code? Would I be forced to change anything syntax-wise with the global code.

For example, let's say I have file A.php. What I want to be able to have is this:

```
namespace A;
class Abc { ... }
```

And then let's say I have some file with global code, call it main.php:

```
include("A.php");
class Abc { ... }
$abc = new Abc(); // Should be global Abc, right?
$abcFromNameSpace = new A\Abc(); // Should be namespace Abc, right?
...
```

As a follow-up question, I'm also wondering what would happen with regard to scope if I were to include a file with namespaces inside another file with namespaces, as opposed to the above example, where main.php only has global code. Would that work like this:

```
namespace A;
class Abc { ... }
```

And then let's say I have some file with global code, call it B.php:

```
namespace B;
include("A.php");
class Abc { ... }
$abc = new B\Abc(); // Should be namepsace B Abc, right?
$abcFromNameSpace = new A\Abc(); // Should be namespace A Abc, right?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you refer to a class that is outside of the current file or class scope, you use its namespace:

```
<?php
namespace B;

$class = new \A\Abc();
```

But if you "use" the namespace in your script, you can leave it out:'

```
<?php
namespace B;

use A\Abc;

$class = new Abc();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, so the scope of namespaces is limited to the file? In the case of the global example (first example), in main.php, if I do $class= new Abc(); then I'm referring to the global class. And if I want to refer to the namespace A's Abc class, I have to do $class = new \A\Abc(); Yes?

Comment: correct. if you don't define a namespace at the top of your file, the class names are looked for in the global scope. Otherwise `Abc()` will be looked for in the files namespace only (unless you prepend a backslash to assert global namespace).

Comment: I see. It seems kind of strange to me, though, that namespaces scope doesn't go beyond the file they are defined in when that file is included in another file. I mean, all the other code becomes part of the file it is being included at the line the include statement is at.