# PHP Namespace will not change after include or require

Tags: php, namespaces

actually my question is very simple. In PHP I can define namespaces in files which will be loaded with require or include.
Example:

content of index.php

```
namespace test;
require('example.php');
die(__NAMESPACE__);
```

content of example.php

```
namespace example;
echo "hello world";
```

If you execute this code, the output will be "test", because the namespace will not change if you include a file with another namespace.

But could you tell me why? How can I imagine the parser?
It could look like:

```
namespace test{}
namespace example{}
// and here it goes on with test, but why I didn´t said namespace test
namespace test{}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Files and Namespaces Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239845/multiple-files-and-namespaces-scope)

Answer (score 0):

In a PHP File, all code after a `namespace` declaration will belong to that namespace. This includes the `require` statements.

Each PHP file has within it its own value for `__NAMESPACE__` that is populated when `namespace` is declared. To access the namespace of another file, you could create a method in `example.php` that returns `__NAMESPACE__`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512398).

Alternately, you could use `get_current_namespaces()` but this won't tell you what namespace belongs to what file.

Comment: Thx. But why does a require not affect the following namespace? A require loads the page into the current page, so all will be one file. And if I would do this manually, it would also work.

Comment: The PHP Interpreter will act as though the many files are one, but will keep them logically separated (appropriately enough: by namespace). The `include` statement just tells the interpreter to be aware of the functions, etc belonging to other files, but while those methods may belong to a different namespace, the `__NAMESPACE__` is concerned only with the namespace of the file in which it was referenced.